# Unexpected value using kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalarToDecibels

Tags: macos, core-audio

I'm getting unexpected values for the volume level using `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalarToDecibels` on my laptop's built-in audio.

```
void volume_test()
{
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
        .mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
        .mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        .mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    AudioObjectID deviceID = kAudioObjectUnknown;
    UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(deviceID);
    OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &address, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &deviceID);
    assert(result == noErr);

    address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar;
    address.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput;

    Float32 volumeScalar = 0;
    dataSize = sizeof(volumeScalar);
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &address, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &volumeScalar);
    assert(result == noErr);

    address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeDecibels;

    Float32 volumeDecibels = 0;
    dataSize = sizeof(volumeDecibels);
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &address, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &volumeDecibels);
    assert(result == noErr);

    address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalarToDecibels;

    Float32 convertedVolumeDecibels = volumeScalar;
    dataSize = sizeof(convertedVolumeDecibels);
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &address, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &convertedVolumeDecibels);
    assert(result == noErr);

    address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeDecibelsToScalar;

    Float32 convertedVolumeScalar = volumeDecibels;
    dataSize = sizeof(convertedVolumeScalar);
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &address, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &convertedVolumeScalar);
    assert(result == noErr);

    NSLog(@"Direct    = %.4f %+2.2f dB", volumeScalar, volumeDecibels);
    NSLog(@"Converted = %.4f %+2.2f dB", convertedVolumeScalar, convertedVolumeDecibels);

    address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeRangeDecibels;

    AudioValueRange decibelRange;
    dataSize = sizeof(decibelRange);
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &address, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &decibelRange);
    assert(result == noErr);

    NSLog(@"dB range %+2.2f ... %+2.2f", decibelRange.mMinimum, decibelRange.mMaximum);
}
```

The output is:

```
Direct    = 0.0620 -47.69 dB
Converted = 0.0620 -59.56 dB
dB range -63.50 ... +0.00
```

The same thing occurs using the underlying `AudioControl` directly.

For reference, Audio MIDI setup shows:

[image: Audio MIDI Setup]

Interestingly, using my external display's audio and the elements from `kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelsForStereo` (since it has no master element), the values match.

Also of note, for the display audio `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeDecibelsToScalarTransferFunction` is `5`, or `kAudioLevelControlTranferFunction2Over1`. Attempting to retrieve `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeDecibelsToScalarTransferFunction` for the laptop fails with the message

```
HALC_ShellObject::GetPropertyData: call to the proxy failed, Error: 2003332927 (who?)
HALPlugIn::ObjectGetPropertyData: got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 2003332927 (who?)
```

which is not a "normal" error message for an unsupported property.

How should `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalarToDecibels` be used?

Comment: Weird. I tried a virtual device and the values matched.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I tried using my display and the values matched. I added a bit more diagnostic info to the question.